# Pandoc. Форматирование текста происходит не корректно

Tags: linux, docx, pandoc

Есть html документ который находится по ссылке: [ссылка](http://92.63.98.4/olimp/_files_materials/doc_1-1-1-b56d7266a3f143de9a42921019dbc4b6/index.html)

Я хочу сохранить его в docx. Для этого использую [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/)

Вот команда:

> pandoc --wrap=none -f html -t docx 'http://92.63.98.4/olimp/_files_materials/doc_1-1-1-b56d7266a3f143de9a42921019dbc4b6/index.html' -s -o test.docx

В итоге в некоторых таблицах получается что текст идет вертикально:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 2):

поковырялся немного. В общем, проблема не с pandoc'ом. Исправлять надо в самом ворде. Дело в том, что таблица слишком широкая. Когда она у Вас в html, всё отображается корректно. При конвертации в docx pandoc пытается ужать её до ширины страницы, и весь текст съезжает, т.к. ширина столбцов становится слишком маленькой. Можете попробовать скопировать всю таблицу, вставить на большой лист и отредактировать её уже там. Или например, в Word 365 у меня открылось почти как надо, но таблица была просто шире самого листа. Повыравнивайте ячейки по центру, исправьте ширину ячеек, объедините те ячейки, которые разделены из-за ограничений конвертации, и всё должно стать норм. Но автоматом вы вряд ли добьётесь нужного результата.